# Which package or option forces footnotes to use symbols?

Tags: footnotes

I've read that footnotes are numbered by default, but in my case, they use symbols by default, and the symbols are pretty ugly: in some cases they overlap the following characters.

Why aren't arabic number used by default in my document, and why doesn't `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` change anything? I unsuccessfully tried disabling packages one by one when it didn't prevent compilation.

Here the header of my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% En-tête et pied de page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\textbf{S}mall \textbf{PA}rticle \textbf{DE}tection}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{Page \thepage/\pageref*{LastPage}}

% page de garde
\usepackage{titling}

% biblio dans la table de matières
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

% symbole TM
\usepackage{textcomp}

% mots clefs
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mot-clefs---}} #1}

% remerciements
\providecommand{\merci}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Remerciements---}} #1}

% Langue
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}

% Pseudo-code
\usepackage[french,onelanguage,ruled,linesnumbered,vlined,titlenotnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\dans}{\upshape\textbf{dans}}
\newcommand{\mettre}{\upshape\textbf{mettre}}
\SetKwInput{KwOut}{Sortie}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{} % non numéroté

% Biblio
\usepackage{cell}

% Figures
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Tableau depuis csv
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% Liens hypertextes
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

EDIT: It turned out that what broke the foot notes was the fact I used `\postauthor` without using `\preauthor`. Easier fix than the solution I accepted.

Comment: I suppose that you have footnotes in a minipage. By default footnotes have arabic numbers, but not in minipages

Comment: I don't think I'm using a minipage, though maybe some packages force this?

Comment: create a _complete_ example which shows your behaviour.

Comment: That was my problem, I could not reproduce the issue on a short document, that's why I asked if any of the packages I use is known to break footnotes. Anyway, @Bernard provided me with a workaround, so I guess this is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `footmisc` package with option `symbols*`. IOt enables the `perpage` option.
You can enable your own list of symbols with `\DefineFNSymbols{mysymbolslist}{…}`, and use it with `\setfnsymbol{mysymbolslist}`. See §§ 1.5–1.7 of the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I had to change it a little bit, and I know my solution is dirty, but well, my report is due soon! `\usepackage[symbols*,perpage]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols*{numbers}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}}
\setfnsymbol{numbers}`

Comment: To further improve the look of my symbols, I ended up adding a `~` after every number.

Comment: Good idea. Try also with a thin unbreakable space (`\,`).